# Sqlite3 or QtSql

Tags: python, sqlite, pyside, qtsql

Need to make a small database for a desktop app built using PySide. I don't know if both(sqlite3 and QtSql) are similar or not, but I'm leaning towards sqlite3. This is because, well, its Pythonic! I wanna know if I'll be missing out on something or not, such as performance, features, etc. (Or is there a convention to use each one considering the project at hand?)

I know this question will get closed because it may not seem constructive enough, and I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtSql isn't a database engine like SQLite is, rather it is software for accessing databases through the Qt environment.

> The Qt SQLite plugin makes it possible to access SQLite databases.
>   SQLite is an in-process database, which means that it is not necessary
>   to have a database server. SQLite operates on a single file, which
>   must be set as the database name when opening a connection. If the
>   file does not exist, SQLite will try to create it. SQLite also
>   supports in-memory databases, simply pass ":memory:" as the database
>   name. - [Source](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/sql-driver.html#qsqlite)